# proof that area of convergence is bounded by a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently looking into the topic of holomorphic functions and their radii of convergence. While I do understand according to the Cauchy's integral formula why a Taylor series converges in a radius r, which is the distance to the nearest singularity from the centre, then I do not understand why the shape of the area has to be precisely a disk, bounded by a circle, contrary to e.g. an ellipse without encompassing the singularities. How to prove that the power series diverges at any point at a distance greater than r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the region $C$ of convergence of a power series about $a$ is always is always such that $D(a,r)\subset C\subset\overline{D(a,r)}$, for some $r>0$, with two exceptions: when $C=\{a\}$ and when $C=\mathbb C$. This is so because if a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ converges at some $z_0\neq a$, then it converges (absolutely) at any $z$ such that $\lvert z-a\rvert<\lvert z_0-a\rvert$. And this is so because$$\bigl\lvert a_n(z-a)^n\bigr\rvert=\bigl\lvert a_n(z_0-a)^n\bigr\rvert.\left\lvert\frac{z-a}{z_0-a}\right\rvert^n,$$and $\left\lvert\frac{z-a}{z_0-a}\right\rvert<1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm sorry as I worded my question a bit ambiguously, but I was rather wondering why the series cannot converge at any point at a distance greater than r, even if it is not a singularity. I'm mostly wondering about why the domain of convergence is always bounded by a circle rather than by any other shape.

Comment: Because if a power series centered at $a$ converges at a point $z_0$, then it will convege at *all* points $z$ such that $\lvert z-a\rvert<\lvert z_0-a\rvert$.

Comment: Imo the answer is missing the point - the fact that the region of convergence of a power  series is a disk (plus some subset of the boundary) has nothing to do with "singularities". Your comment above is imp the whole point.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich If the OP agrees with you (and I suppose that he will), then I will edit my answer in the sense that you are suggesting.

Comment: Indeed that is what I am asking for. If we take the definition of a Taylor series as a power series defined from derivatives, then I can't spot the reason why the diversion starts exactly at a distance r in any given direction, while I can understand why the whole function converges within the radius of convergence. This would imply that the polynomial indeed converges across the whole disk, but doesn't explain why everywhere outside the disk it diverges as opposed to, for example, a case of convergence across an elliptic domain which contains the subset of the disk.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the exact explanation needed.

Comment: Oddly enough, I feel like this gives a correct but still somewhat unsatisfactory answer. In a way, it feels surprising that the $\infty$-norm (=squares) on $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$ is equivalent to the $2$-norm and will hence also result in disks as domains of convergence. Maybe the point with respect to this is, that the $\infty$-norm is a norm and not an absolute value on $\mathbb{C}$ (and if that were the case, then maybe we would have squares).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the Cauchy Integral Formula or any other complex analysis, it's just simple  inequalities.

Let $R$ be the supremum of $|z|$ such that $\sum a_nz^n$ converges. The definition of $R$ shows that

> > If $|z|>R$ then $\sum a_nz^n$ diverges.

In fact anything can happen for $|z|=R$, but

> > If $|z|<R$ then $\sum a_nz^n$ converges.

Proof: The definition of $R$ shows that there exists $w$ with $|w|>|z|$ such that $\sum a_na^n$ converges. Hence $a_nw^n\to0$, so there exists $c$ with $|a_nw^n|\le c$ for all $n$. Now $$\sum|a_nz^n|\le c\sum|z/w|^n<\infty,$$since $|z/w|<1$.